# Modification in shm.c in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, shared-libraries, kernel-module

I want to modify `shm.c` in Linux, and for that I did the followings:

1. Downloaded the Linux source on my device.
2. Recompiled linux kernel with the source code that I downloaded.
3. After many verification, I confirmed that it's actually my source code which is running now

After I made modification in `shmget()` or `shmat()` functions these modification does work.

I doubt that the functions in which I am making changes are not the actual `shmget()` or `shmat()` functions because their name is `shmget()` and the implementation is with the name `do_shmget()` and so on.

So my question is that how can I know that which is the functions that is actually called when I do `shmget()` or `shmat()` or is it possible that the implementation is with the name `do_shmget()` or so?

Code reference:  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/ipc/shm.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know that which is the functions that is actually called when I do `shmget()` or `shmat()`?

The kernel function, which is called when user-space uses some syscall, is defined as

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE<N>(<name>, ...)
```

where `<N>` is the number the syscall's arguments, `<name>` is the name of the syscall, and parameters after the `<name>` are types and names of the syscall parameters.

E.g., for `shmget` syscall, corresponded function definition is ([ipc/shm.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17-rc1/source/ipc/shm.c#L713)):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(shmget, key_t, key, size_t, size, int, shmflg)
{
    return ksys_shmget(key, size, shmflg);
}
```

As you can see, the syscall function calls `ksys_shmget()`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that when I multiply (-1) with the return value of shmget i.e. 
return ( -1 * ksys_shmget(key, size, shmflg));

It still return positive int value that is the id of the shared memory. Why does it still returns the positive value? what can be the possible problem?

Comment: What is the reason of `-1` multiplication? If you want to signal about an error, return `-EINVAL`, or `-ENOMEM`.

Comment: The reason to multiply -1 was to know that it is actually the right function and file from which the shm.h header file is getting the definition of shmget. I would confirm me that I am on the right location with the right file now, so if I want to modify something then I can do it now.